# Safari not displaying Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

Uploaded a Web Site built with Dreamweaver. Google and Firefox display the website correctly but Safari has issues with on of the div's. Checked the site via Inspect Element in both Safari and Google, with the following results.

In Safari

```
<div id="cycle" class="fluid" style="position: relative; width: 0px; height: 0px;"></div>
```

In Google

```
<div id="cycle" class="fluid" style="position: relative; width: 440px; height: 432px;"></div>
```

The Site also displays correctly on Mobile devices using Safari. it is only the Desktop Version that is causing grief.

Following is the CSS for the Desktop size

```
.gridContainer {
width: 89.3181%;
max-width: 1232px;
padding-left: 0.3409%;
padding-right: 0.3409%;
margin: auto;
clear: none;
float: none;
margin-left: auto;
}
#header {
}
#nav {
}
#cycle {
width: 58.0152%;
clear: none;
float: left;
margin-left: 0;
border: solid black 2px;
position:inherit;
}
#content {
width: 39.6183%;
clear: none;
float: right;
margin-left: 9.1603%;
border: solid black 2px;
}
#footer {
}
#circles {
}
.zeroMargin_desktop {
margin-left: 0;
}
.hide_desktop {
display: none;
}
}
```

The website is as yet incomplete www.drophatproductions.com/Test/index.html

Thanks in advance for your help

Barb

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML code in your question. It looks like you may have tried to include snapshots but they did not post.

Comment: Add some obtuse styles like `width:1000px;height:500px;background:purple;font-size:6em;` then gradually change them and see what causes it to disappear.  I can't think of any reason off the top of my head why it would be this way.

Comment: `#cycle` is 0 x 0 in Chrome for Windows and Firefox for Windows for me. If you disable JavaScript and refresh your page, `#cycle` shows up. The fault resides in the JS you have added to do the cycling.

Comment: Safari might be trying to be smart and hide the div because nothing is in it.  I would try putting something in it like a non-breaking space.

Comment: Issue not with css, Its with cycle JavaScript. it calling Before loading images

Answer (score 0):

Change your script like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
   $('#cycle').cycle({ 
        fx:    'fade', 
        speed:  3000 
     });
}); 
</script>
```